# Ball $X^*$ is weak-star metrizable iff X is separable in Conway's book.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

This is a Theorem in Conway's book
[image]

[image]

I don't understand in the third paragraph why there are open sets $\{U_n:n\geq1\}$ in $(ball X^*,wk^*)$ such that $0\in U_n$ and $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}U_n=\{0\}$. By the definition of the relative weak-star topology on ball $X^*$, for each $n$, there exists a finite set $F_n$ contained in $X$ such that $$\{x^*\in\text{ball }X^*:|\langle x,x^*\rangle|<1 \text{ for all }x\in F_n\}\subseteq U_n.$$ 
Can someone explain this for me？ Thank you so much!!

Comment: You cannot use @ to ping someone who hasn't already commented on the current post.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(\operatorname{ball} X^*, \mathrm{wk}^*)$ is metrizable, that means by definition that there is a metric $d$ on $\operatorname{ball} X^*$ which induces the weak-* topology.  In particular, the $d$-balls $B_d(x,r) = \{y \in \operatorname{ball} X^* : d(x,y) < r\}$ are all weak-* open.  So take $U_n = B_d(0, 1/n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get it! But how to explain By the definition of the relative weak-star topology on ball $X^*$, for each $n$, there exists a finite set $F_n$ contained in $X$ such that $$\{x^*\in\text{ball }X^*:|\langle x,x^*\rangle|<1 \text{ for all }x\in F_n\}\subseteq U_n.$$

Comment: @AnswerLee: As it says, this is quite literally the definition of the weak-* topology.  See Definition IV.1.8 and the explanation of "induced by seminorms" immediately following Definition IV.1.1.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Can I ask you another question in the prove? Why ${^\perp}(F^\perp)$ is the closed linear span of $F$ and this subspace of $X$ is separable.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have time to look at this right now.  I suggest you ask it as a new question.